# Proof by induction of summation inequality: $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac1{3^n}\ge 1+\frac{2n}3$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction

Proof by induction of summation inequality: $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac1{3^n}\ge 1+\frac{2n}3$

We start with $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac1{3^n}\ge 1+\frac{2n}3$$ for all positive integers.

I have finished the basic step, the hypothesis is easy too, but I do not know what to do for n+1:

$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac1{3^n}+\frac1{3^{n+1}} \ge 1+\frac{2n}3 +\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}$$

Can you help me from here?

Comment: Instead of $1+\frac 12+\frac13+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{3^n}+\frac1{3^{n+1}}$ you should look at $1+\frac 12+\frac13+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{3^n}+\cdots+\frac1{3^{n+1}}$

Comment: so for the part after 1/3^n, it gives a sum for k starting from 3^n+1 until 3^(n+1) for 1/k right?

Comment: Yes indeed, you add an extra $\frac1{3^n+1}+\frac1{3^n+2}+\cdots+\frac1{3^{n+1}-1}+\frac1{3^{n+1}}$

Comment: Thank you! do we get then, 1 +2n/3+ that sum, is it enough to just show that the last sum is grater than 2/3?

Comment: yes, I think so.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: In the induction step, you need to show that your induction hypothesis implies that $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{3^n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{3^{n + 1}} \geq 1 + \frac{2(n + 1)}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum on the LHS is

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{3^n} \frac1k$$

The hypothesis is that $S_n\ge 1+\frac{2n}{3}$

Base case $n=0$. As $S_0=1\ge1+0=1$, the case $n=0$ is true.

Assume true for $n$, prove

$$S_n+\sum_{k=3^n+1}^{3^{n+1}}\frac1k\ge 1+\frac{2n}{3}+\frac{2}{3}$$

As

$$\sum_{k=3^n+1}^{3^{n+1}}\frac1k\ge\sum_{k=3^n+1}^{3^{n+1}}\frac1{3^{n+1}}=\frac{2\cdot3^n}{3^{n+1}}=\frac23$$

is true at $n=0$, the induction holds.